# Arranging elements in C array so there are no gaps

Tags: c, arrays

I have a regular array of structs in C, in a program that runs every second and updates all the data in the structs. When a condition is met, one of the elements gets cleared and is used as a free slot for new element (in this case timers) that might come in at any point.

What I do is just to parse all the elements of the array looking for active elements requiring updates. But even if the amount of elements is small (<2000), I feel this is wasting time going through the inactive ones. Is there a way I can keep the array gap-free so I just need to iterate though the number of currently allocated elements?

Comment: Is the order in which you scan your structs important?

Comment: @AraK Not really, they only need to store their own index number, but other than that, the order is unimportant (can be updated to the new index without issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the specific order of the elements does not matter, it can be done very easily.

If you have your array `A` and the number of active elements `N`, you can then add an element `E` like this:

```
A[N++] = E;
```

and remove the element at index `I` like this:

```
A[I] = A[--N];
```

So how does this work? Well, it's fairly simple. We want the array to only store active elements, so we may assume that the array is like that when we start doing either of these things.

Adding an element will always put it at the end, and since all elements currently in the array, as well as the newly added element, will be active, we can safely add one to the end.

Removing an element is done by moving the last element to take over the array index of the element we want to remove. Thus, `A[0..I-1]` is active, as well as `A[I+1..N]`, and by moving `A[N]` to `A[I]`, the entire range `A[0..N-1]` is active (`A[N]` is not active, because it no longer exists - we moved it to `A[I]`, and that's why we decrease N by 1).

If you're removing elements while iterating over them to update them, note that you can only increment your loop counter after processing an element which *doesn't* get removed, since otherwise, you would never process the moved elements.

Comment: Nice explanation, I get it. Although, I never used the "--N" notation, is it like "N--"?

Comment: @Delirium: No, `N--` returns the value of `N`, then decrements it by 1; `--N` decrements `N`, then returns the new value. (`++` works in the same way, expects it increments instead of decrementing.) You want to use `--N` here because your array elements are indexed `[0..N-1]`; if you used `N--`, you would try to access A[N], which does not exist.

Comment: Oh I see! That explains some errors I ran into a long time ago...great to know, thank you! What is the proper name for this operation?

Comment: @Delirium_4: You mean decrementing? The two forms don't really have a special name: `N--` is called a postfix decrement, whereas `--N` is called a prefix decrement - that is, they're distinguished in writing through specifying if the operator is pre- or postfixed to the operand.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple way to accomplish this:

```
void remove(struct foo *foo_array, int *n)
{
   struct foo *src = foo_array, *dst = foo_array;
   int num_removed = 0;

   for (int i=0; i<*n; ++i)
   {
      // Do we want to remove this? (should_remove() left as exercise for reader.)
      if (should_remove(src))
      {
         // yes, remove; advance src without advancing dst
         ++src;
         ++num_removed;
      }
      else if (src != dst)
      {
         // advance src and dst (with copy)
         *dst++ = *src++;
      }
      else
      {
         // advance both pointers (no copy)
         ++src;
         ++dst;
      }
   }

   // update size of array
   *n -= num_removed;
}
```

The idea is that you keep track of how many elements of the array are valid (`*n` here), and pass its pointer as an "in/out parameter".  `remove()` decides which elements to remove and copies the ones that are out of place.  Notice that this is O(n) regardless of how many elements are decided to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Traversing 2,000 entries per second is negligible. It's really not worth optimizing. If you really feel you must, swap the inactive entry for the last active entry.

Comment: Well, it's mostly curiosity, I am not a seasoned programmer and would like to increase my skills. So you mean that when I remove an element, I store the "rightmost" (considering [0] as left) element into it?

Comment: That's certainly one way, if the order doesn't particularly matter.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a linked list behavior in your struct, i.e. a pointer member pointing to the next active element?

You would have to update these pointers on element activation and deactivation.

**EDIT:** This method is not suitable for dynamically resized arrays, because that may change the memory object's address, invalidating the pointers used by the list..

Comment: Although I know how to write a linked list, I never understood how to rearrange them properly...do you have any good reference material I can use?

Comment: @Delirium_4, to insert into a singly linked list, you assign to the new element's `next` pointer the value of the previous element's `next` pointer. Then you update the previous element's `next` pointer to point to your new element. To delete an element, you assign to the previous element's `next` pointer the value of your deleted element's `next` pointer. What kind of rearranging do you mean?

Comment: Mixing linked lists (or any sort of pointers to array elements) with an array that might dynamically grow (and thus change address) is a really really bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you have a great reason for not using a linked list. If you do the implementation well, you'll get O(1) inserts, O(1) removals and you'll only ever need to keep (and iterate over)active structs. There'd be some memory overhead... for even moderately sized structs, though, even a doubly-linked list would be pretty efficient. The nice thing about this approach is that you can keep elements in their insertion order without extra computational overhead.

Answer (score 0):

A few alternatives come to mind, choose according to your needs:

1) Leave it as it is unless you are having some performance issues or need to scale up.

2) Add a "next" pointer to each struct to use it as an element in a doubly linked list. Keep two lists, one for the active ones and one for the unused ones. Depending on how you use the struts, also consider making the list doubly linked. (You can also still have the elements in an array if you need to index the structs, or you can stop using the array if not.)

3) If you don't need indices (or order) of the structs in the array to be constant, move unused entries to the end of the array. Then when you iterate through the array from the beginning, you can stop whenever you reach the first unused one. (You can store the index of the last active struct so that whenever a struct is deactivated you can just have it switch places with the last active one, and then decrement the index of the last active struct.)